# Individual code formatting for files in Emacs

Tags: emacs, formatting, indentation, code-formatting

Is there equivalent plugin like modeline_magic from VIM?

So each file could look like e.g.:

```
/* vim: set tabstop=8:softtabstop=8:shiftwidth=8:noexpandtab */ 
int main(int, char *) {}
```

and indentation would be passed to other clients?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add local (file) variables by having a line formatted as

```
-*- mode: modename; var: value; ... -*-
```

at the start of your file. Any number of `var: value;` pairs can appear in the line. If you're finding that you have too many local variables, you can change the style to

```
 # Local Variables:  
 # mode: python      
 # comment-column: 0 
 # End:
```

Emacs searches for the string "Local Variables", and is smart enough to work out that the prefix and suffix (in this case `#` and nothing) should be reused for the following lines. This means that if the file is something other than python, you can change the prefix/suffix to match the different comment characters, e.g. `/*` and `*/` for ANSI C.

You can read more at the [emacs manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Specifying-File-Variables.html#Specifying-File-Variables).

Comment: I am afraid I have to say it once again my life: Emacs is incredible! 

Thanks!

Comment: @test30 If this post answers your question, why not accept it? :)

Comment: @itsjeyd you are right, I forgot about checking as accepted :D

Comment: @event_jr I think you should post this editorconfig.org as a separate answer, because it's worth spreading it! What a pity it is not supported by Netbeans, at least it is not listed on website. actually "here":https://blogs.oracle.com/geertjan/entry/editorconfig_and_netbeans_ide is a plugin which supports it.